# PHP Serialize All POST Data

Tags: php

I want to serialize all POST data from HTML form with PHP. I have tried with this code: `serialize($_POST);` but as result I get serialized INPUT Names and Values together, I want to get serialized only Values of INPUT.

Comment: Not sure why you need only values, try  `serialize(array_values($_POST))`, but still there be numeric keys

Comment: Thats sloved problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you need to serialize only array values - use `array_values` function. After using this function you will have your array values, but keys will be numeric:

```
serialize(array_values($_POST))
```